# Convert Bytes to Buf with bytes library

Tags: rust, reqwest

I'm trying to convert the result of a reqwest file download in to a type which implements the [`Read`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/trait.Read.html) trait. Reqwest has given back a [`Bytes`](https://docs.rs/bytes/latest/bytes/struct.Bytes.html) type. Bytes does not seem to implement `Read` trait but in the same library there is `Buf` which does implement `Read`.

I have been trying to find a way to convert `Bytes` to `Buf` but I have not found a way. Am I going about this the right way if I want to get something which implements [`Read`](https://docs.rs/bytes/latest/bytes/trait.Buf.html) and is there a way to do it by converting `Bytes` to `Buf`?

Comment: Bytes is a struct that implement the trait Buf, what you ask don't make sense. Bytes implement AsRef and Deref that return a slice if you want.

Comment: @Stargateur well I'm facing the error "the trait `std::io::Read` is not implemented for `bytes::Bytes`". Is this something I can get working with Bytes?

Comment: Take a look on https://github.com/tokio-rs/bytes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that [`Bytes`](https://docs.rs/bytes/latest/bytes/struct.Bytes.html) already implements [`Buf`](https://docs.rs/bytes/latest/bytes/trait.Buf.html#). But **you need to have the trait in scope** for using it:

```rust
fn main() {
    use bytes::Bytes;
    use bytes::Buf;

    let mut buf = Bytes::from("Hello world");
    assert_eq!(b'H', buf.get_u8());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=628f9da59ab33bdf6ccef41715263019)

With that in mind, if you need a [`Read`](https://docs.rs/bytes/latest/bytes/buf/struct.Reader.html#impl-Read) object, you can call the method [`reader`](https://docs.rs/bytes/latest/bytes/trait.Buf.html#method.reader) to get such type:

```rust
fn main() {
    use bytes::Bytes;
    use bytes::Buf;
    use std::io::Read;
    
    let mut buf = Bytes::from("Hello world");
    let mut reader: Box<dyn Read> = Box::new(buf.reader()) as Box<dyn Read>;
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2b5a5718a549a0c8b0e56c55e1ee34f2)